# error while making new flex project

Tags: java, apache-flex

If I start a new Flex 4 project with Application server type set to
'none' all is well.

If a new project has it's Application server type set to J2EE - use
blazdes, the default
mxml document immediately throws a 'Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8
sequence error upon compilation.

Comment: Could you copy-paste the relevant part of the stack trace here? It could give other people some more insight into your problem. Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @Anzeo Configuration error encountered on line 21, column 14: 'Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. test(Project name) Unknown flex problem